# Match only one character out of a set of characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, command-line-interface, user-input

I'm writing a CLI program in Python and would like to ask the user to choose one of 3 options by pressing a key on the keyboard, say A, B and C.

The user should be able to use only a, b, c, A, B and C to specify an option.

AAA, BB, AB, CBA.. should all be invalid options.

To achieve this, I tried using the re library so far, with unsuccessful attempts:

```
>>> p = re.compile('[abc]', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> p.match('ab') == None
False
>>> p = re.compile('[a|b|c]', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> p.match('ab') == None
False
>>> p = re.compile('[a|b|c]{1}', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> p.match('ab') == None
False
```

Maybe using regular expressions is a bit too much for such a simple task, but I would like to know how this could be done using regex. It seems quite simple but somehow can't get it to work...

Comment: You need `p.fullmatch`

Comment: That should work without regular expressions: `if value.lower() in {'a', 'b', 'c'}:`